# Django: Getting NoReverseMatch Error While Attempting to Use Slug in URLs

Tags: python, django

I am a beginner learning Django through building an app, called PhoneReview. It will store reviews related to the latest mobile phone. It will also display phone brands, along with the associated phone models and their reviews.

I have already created models, views and the template files. Right now, I am facing a problem. While attempting to use slug, I am getting NoReverseMatch Error. It looks like this:

```
NoReverseMatch at /index
Reverse for 'modellist' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['phonemodel/(?P<slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$']
```

However, I didn't face any problem with while using primary key  in urls.py. The problem is occurring when I attempt to use slug in the URLs.

Here are my codes of **models.py** located inside PhoneReview folder:

```
from django.db import models
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify

# Create your models here.
class Brand(models.Model):
    brand_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    origin = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    manufacturing_since = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.brand_name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.brand_name)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

class PhoneModel(models.Model):
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    model_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    launch_date = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    platform = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.model_name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.model_name)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

class Review(models.Model):
    phone_model = models.ManyToManyField(PhoneModel, related_name='reviews')
    review_article = models.TextField()
    date_published = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    link = models.TextField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.review_article
```

Here are my codes of **urls.py** located inside PhoneReview folder:

```
from . import views
from django.urls import path

app_name = 'PhoneReview'

urlpatterns = [
    path('index', views.BrandListView.as_view(), name='brandlist'),
    path('phonemodel/<slug:slug>', views.ModelView.as_view(), name='modellist'),
    path('details/<slug:slug>', views.ReviewView.as_view(), name='details'),
]
```

Here are my codes of **views.py** located inside PhoneReview folder:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.views import generic
from .models import Brand, PhoneModel, Review


class BrandListView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'PhoneReview/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'all_brands'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Brand.objects.all()


class ModelView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'PhoneReview/phonemodel.html'
    context_object_name = 'all_model_name'

    def get_queryset(self):
        self.brand = get_object_or_404(Brand, slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
        return PhoneModel.objects.filter(brand=self.brand)

class ReviewView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Review
    template_name = 'PhoneReview/details.html'
```

Here are my codes of **apps.py** located inside PhoneReview folder:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class PhonereviewConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'PhoneReview'
```

Here are my codes of **index.html** located inside templates folder:

```
{% extends 'PhoneReview/base.html' %}

{% load static %}

{% block title%}
Brand List
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<!--Page content-->
<h1>This is Brand List Page</h1>
<h2>Here is the list of the brands</h2>
    <ul>
        {% for brand in all_brands %}
<!--            <li>{{ brand.brand_name }}</li>-->
            <li><a href = "{% url 'PhoneReview:modellist' phonemodel.slug %}">{{ brand.brand_name }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
<img src="{% static "images/brandlist.jpg" %}" alt="Super Mario Odyssey" /> <!-- New line -->
{% endblock %}
```

Here are my codes of **phonemodel.html** located inside templates folder:

```
{% extends 'PhoneReview/base.html' %}

{% load static %}

{% block title%}
Phone Model Page
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<!--Page content-->
<h1>This is Phone Model Page</h1>
<h2>Here is the phone model</h2>
    <ul>
        {% for phonemodel in all_model_name %}
            <li><a href = "{% url 'PhoneReview:details' review.slug %}">{{ phonemodel.model_name }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
<img src="{% static "images/brandlist.jpg" %}" alt="Super Mario Odyssey" /> <!-- New line -->
{% endblock %}
```

Here are my codes of **details.html** located inside templates folder:

```
{% extends 'PhoneReview/base.html' %}
{% load static %}

<html>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "css/style.css" %}">


<html lang="en">

{% block title%}Details{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<h1>This is the Details Page</h1>

<h2>Review:</h2>
<p>{{ review.review_article }}</p>

<h2>News Link:</h2>
<p>{{ review.link }}</p>
{% endblock %}
</html>
```

Am I doing anything wrong in **index.html** and **phonemodel.html**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `index.html` instead of `phonemodel.slug` it should be `brand.slug`

```
{% for brand in all_brands %}
<!--        <li>{{ brand.brand_name }}</li>-->
            <li><a href = "{% url 'PhoneReview:modellist' brand.slug %}">{{ brand.brand_name }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

Same with your `phonemodel.html`

```
 {% for phonemodel in all_model_name %}
            <li><a href = "{% url 'PhoneReview:details' phonemodel.slug %}">{{ phonemodel.model_name }}</a></li>
 % endfor %}
```

Comment: It works! Thank you! Now, I am facing the last and final problem. When I click on the phone models, like Galaxy S10, I am supposed to be taken to details.html page, which has a review of the device, along with the news link. However, when I click on Galaxy S10, I am getting "Page not found (404)". I am going to post a new question about the issue.

Comment: I have posted a new question about the issue. Would you please take a look at it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58872348/django-getting-404-error-while-attempting-to-use-slug-in-url