# Django: Getting 404 Error While Attempting to Use Slug in URL

Tags: python, django

I am a beginner learning Django through building an app, called PhoneReview. It will store reviews related to the latest mobile phone. It will also display phone brands, along with the associated phone models and their reviews.

When I go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/index, I see this page:
[image]

When I click on **Samsung**, I see this page:

[image]

Up to this is fine.
But when I click on any phone model, like **Galaxy S10**, I get 404 error. It looks like this:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/details/galaxy-s10
Raised by:  PhoneReview.views.ReviewView
No review found matching the query

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

When I click on Samsung, I am supposed to see the **details.html** page, which has the review of the phone, along with the news link. Instead, I am getting the 404 error.

Here are my codes of **models.py** located inside PhoneReview folder:

```
from django.db import models
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify

# Create your models here.
class Brand(models.Model):
    brand_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    origin = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    manufacturing_since = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.brand_name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.brand_name)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

class PhoneModel(models.Model):
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    model_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    launch_date = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    platform = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.model_name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.model_name)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

class Review(models.Model):
    phone_model = models.ManyToManyField(PhoneModel, related_name='reviews')
    review_article = models.TextField()
    date_published = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    link = models.TextField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.review_article

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.phone_model)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Here are my codes of **urls.py** located inside PhoneReview folder:

```
from . import views
from django.urls import path

app_name = 'PhoneReview'

urlpatterns = [
    path('index', views.BrandListView.as_view(), name='brandlist'),
    path('phonemodel/<slug:slug>', views.ModelView.as_view(), name='modellist'),
    path('details/<slug:slug>', views.ReviewView.as_view(), name='details'),
]
```

Here are my codes of **views.py** located inside PhoneReview folder:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.views import generic
from .models import Brand, PhoneModel, Review


class BrandListView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'PhoneReview/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'all_brands'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Brand.objects.all()


class ModelView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'PhoneReview/phonemodel.html'
    context_object_name = 'all_model_name'

    def get_queryset(self):
        self.brand = get_object_or_404(Brand, slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
        return PhoneModel.objects.filter(brand=self.brand)

class ReviewView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Review
    template_name = 'PhoneReview/details.html'
```

Here are my codes of **apps.py** located inside PhoneReview folder:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class PhonereviewConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'PhoneReview'
```

Here are my codes of **index.html** located inside templates folder:

```
{% extends 'PhoneReview/base.html' %}

{% load static %}

{% block title%}
Brand List
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<!--Page content-->
<h1>This is Brand List Page</h1>
<h2>Here is the list of the brands</h2>
    <ul>
        {% for brand in all_brands %}
<!--            <li>{{ brand.brand_name }}</li>-->
            <li><a href = "{% url 'PhoneReview:modellist' brand.slug %}">{{ brand.brand_name }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
<img src="{% static "images/brandlist.jpg" %}" alt="Super Mario Odyssey" /> <!-- New line -->
{% endblock %}
```

Here are my codes of **phonemodel.html** located inside templates folder:

```
{% extends 'PhoneReview/base.html' %}

{% load static %}

{% block title%}
Phone Model Page
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<!--Page content-->
<h1>This is Phone Model Page</h1>
<h2>Here is the phone model</h2>
    <ul>
        {% for phonemodel in all_model_name %}
            <li><a href = "{% url 'PhoneReview:details' phonemodel.slug %}">{{ phonemodel.model_name }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
<img src="{% static "images/brandlist.jpg" %}" alt="Super Mario Odyssey" /> <!-- New line -->
{% endblock %}
```

Here are my codes of **details.html** located inside templates folder:

```
{% extends 'PhoneReview/base.html' %}
{% load static %}

<html>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "css/style.css" %}">


<html lang="en">

{% block title%}Details{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<h1>This is the Details Page</h1>

<h2>Review:</h2>
<p>{{ review.review_article }}</p>

<h2>News Link:</h2>
<p>{{ review.link }}</p>
{% endblock %}
</html>
```

Am I doing anything wrong with **details.html**? When I was using `<pk>` in urls.py, instead of `<slug:slug>`, it was working perfectly.

Update 1: When I try to add a review of the phone model through Django admin, I get this error: 
`"<Review: The Galaxy S10 is a fitting 10th anniversary phone for Samsung and its storied S series. >" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.`

Update 2: I have got the aforementioned issue fixed by removing these lines in `class Review` on `models.py`:

`def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.slug = slugify(self.phone_model)
            super().save(*args, **kwargs)`

Comment: I helped you with that `get_object_or_404` method and I guess that you didn't have that field in first, you probably added this afterward and I guess that the model don't have that slug. Confirm me if that model has that slug.

Comment: If you don't have that slug or had a different slug then resave that model so that the slug can be saved.

Comment: `class ModelView` has `get_object_or_404`. But `class ReviewView` doesn't have it. Are you telling me to add it in `class ReviewView`?

Comment: `class Review` has `slug`. I have saved the slug with these codes: `def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.phone_model)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)`. Please, see my codes on `models.py`.

Comment: @FaisalManzer Please, see my previous comments.

Comment: I am telling you to check that the `slug` is really `samsung` for that Samsung model.

Comment: @FaisalManzer I had some other issues with the codes. I have got them solved. Now, I am facing another similar 404 issue. I have posted a new question about it. Would you please take a look at it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58884505/django-404-error-appears-while-trying-to-use-slug-in-urls